# Angular observable updating view just once

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-components

I'm having a problem with a chat-like app which I'm developing. I got a conversation component which contains all the related messages. Those messages has an internal state which displays different icons inside its template. I've registered 3 observables inside the app.component, which are these

**app.component.ts**

```
   vm.socketService.newReadStatus$.subscribe(read_status => {
        console.log('NEW SOCKET READ STATUS', read_status);
    });

    vm.socketService.newSocketConversation$.subscribe(conversation => {
        console.log('NEW SOCKET CONVERSATION', conversation);
    });

    vm.socketService.newSocketMessage$.subscribe(socket_msg => {
        const monitor = vm.infoService.getStructure(socket_msg.sid),
            conversation = monitor.getConversation(socket_msg.cid),
            message = conversation.getMessage(socket_msg.mid);

        message.setConfirmed();
    });
```

This is the message class structure (I'll post just the relevant part)

**message.ts**

```
    constructor(message_data) {
            _.extend(this, {
                _account_id: message_data.aid,
                _conversation_id: message_data.cid,
                _message_id: message_data.mid,
                _structure_id: message_data.sid,
                _data: message_data.data,
                _extra: message_data.extra,
                _recipient: message_data.recipient,
                _render: message_data.render,
                _sender: message_data.sender,
                _seq: message_data.seq,
                _status: message_data.status,
                _time: message_data.time ? message_data.time : moment(),
                _temp_id: message_data._temp_id
            });

            if (message_data.sending_status) {
                this._sending_status = message_data.sending_status;
            } else {
                this.setConfirmed();
            }
        }

setConfirmed() {
        this._sending_status = {
            pending: false,
            confirmed: true,
            error: false
        };
    }
```

With his component

```
export class MessageComponent {

    @Input() message: Message;

    constructor() {
    }

    getIcon() {
        const vm = this, msg_status = vm.message.current_status;
        let icon = '';
        switch (msg_status) {
            case 'pending':
                icon = 'access_time';
                break;
            case 'confirmed':
                icon = 'done';
                break;
            case 'error':
                icon = 'error_outline';
                break;
        }
        return icon;
    }

}
```

And this is the part inside `chat-conversation.component` (just the relevant part with message sending)

```
 sendMessage() {
        const vm = this;
        if (vm.messageForm.valid) {
            const last_seq = vm.conversation.getLastSeq(),
                _temp_id = last_seq ? last_seq + 1 : 0,
                msg_data = {
                    aid: vm.conversation.account_id,
                    mid: _temp_id,
                    sid: vm.monitor.structure_id,
                    cid: vm.conversation.conversation_id,
                    _temp_id: _temp_id,
                    data: {
                        text: vm.messageForm.get('message').value
                    },
                    seq: last_seq,
                    recipient: {
                        name: vm.conversation.name,
                        type: vm.conversation.type
                    },
                    render: 'staff',
                    sender: {
                        name: vm.infoService.getCurrentUser().name,
                        userId: vm.infoService.getCurrentUserID(),
                        type: 'staff'
                    },
                    status: {
                        timestamps: {
                            staffRead: new Date().valueOf()
                        }
                    },
                    sending_status: {
                        pending: true
                    },
                    time: null,
                    type: 'text'
                };

            vm.conversation.addMessage(msg_data).then(() => {
                const temp_message = vm.conversation.getTempMessage(_temp_id);
                if (temp_message) {
                    vm.apiService.post('chat/message', {
                        conversation: vm.conversation.conversation_id,
                        text: vm.messageForm.get('message').value,
                        recipient: 'staff',
                        sender: 'staff',
                        _temp_id: _temp_id
                    }).subscribe(
                        response => {
                            temp_message.message_id = response.mid;
                        }, error => {
                            temp_message.setError();
                            console.log('NEW MESSAGE ERROR', error);
                        }
                    );
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

It should work like this

- Send message using APIs
- Message come back from socket
- Class (and view) gets updated with new status

The problem is that the view is being updated just once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a very **loooooooooong** debugging process I discovered that I was always searching for the same `message.id` updating it only the first time.
Shame on me